# "Argument type *[] is not assignable to parameter type array" error in IntelliJ with vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, jsdoc

I'm getting this weird error in IntelliJ that I'm not sure how to fix. I have a very simple component that you can see below. This is a pure vanilla JS component.

**Error**

> Argument type *[] is not assignable to parameter type array

[image]

**Component**

```
  var MyPolylineComponent = function () {
    this.polylines = [];
  };

  /**
   * Saves the given polylines to the collection
   * @param {array} path An array of google map lat,lng positions to create path
   * @return {undefined}
   */
  MyPolylineComponent.prototype.addPolyline = function (path) {
    this.polylines.push(createPolyline(path));
  };
```

**Usage**

```
var polylines = new MyPolylineComponent();
polylines.addPolyline([newMarker.position, distanceMarkerPosition]);
```

If I remove the JSDoc comment it goes away so it's something to do with that, but I *am* passing it an array like my JSDoc is asking for. I tried different return values and such as well but I'm not having any luck getting that warning to go away.

***EDIT***

As requested, here's the createPolyline function

```
  /**
   * Creates and returns a styled Google Maps Polyline instance with the given path
   * @private
   * @param {array} path An array of google map lat,lng positions to create path
   * @return {object} Returns a Google Maps Polyline instance
   */
  var createPolyline = function (path) {
    var map = mapsManager.getMap(); // just retrieves a GMaps map instance
    return new google.maps.Polyline({
      map: map,
      path: path,
      strokeColor: '#4285F4',
      strokeOpacity: 0.4
    });
  };
```

Comment: Please show the definition of `createPolyline`.

Comment: You have `var Polylines` with a capital P, then lowercase p `polylines.addPolyline(...)` - is that just a typo in your question?

Comment: Yes, sorry, typo when renaming functions for the post. Ill fix!

Comment: @torazaburo added!

Answer (score 0):

That is an editor's bug, and is going to be fixed in the next IDEA version (2017.3), see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29427.